# API URL data not able to fetch, status code 401

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to get data from the API URL to Excel file
[https://www.nseindia.com/api/historical/indicesHistory?indexType=NIFTY%2050&from=28-07-2023&to=28-07-2023][nseindia api]
it is just OHLC value for nifty index.

I have made variable to date input.
I am getting this error:

> Failed to fetch data from the URL: `Status Code: 401`

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

def NseHistoricalData(index_type, from_date, to_date):
    url = f"https://www.nseindia.com/api/historical/indicesHistory?indexType={index_type}&from={from_date}&to={to_date}"
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36',
        'Referer': 'https://www.nseindia.com/',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
    session = requests.Session()
    response_session = session.get(url, headers=headers)

    try:
        if response_session.status_code == 200:
            data = response_session.json()['data']['indexCloseOnlineRecords']
            if data:
                # Extract the required values
                eod_open_index_val = data[0]['EOD_OPEN_INDEX_VAL']
                eod_high_index_val = data[0]['EOD_HIGH_INDEX_VAL']
                eod_close_index_val = data[0]['EOD_CLOSE_INDEX_VAL']
                eod_low_index_val = data[0]['EOD_LOW_INDEX_VAL']

                # Open the Excel file
                file_name = r"C:\Users\vhind\Desktop\a\Zerodha\Version_v0\Zerodha\NSE_data.xlsm"
                wb = xw.Book(file_name)
                sheet_name = "Main"

                # Write the extracted values to the sheet
                wb.sheets[sheet_name].range('M8').value = eod_open_index_val
                wb.sheets[sheet_name].range('M9').value = eod_high_index_val
                wb.sheets[sheet_name].range('M10').value = eod_close_index_val
                wb.sheets[sheet_name].range('M11').value = eod_low_index_val

                # Save the changes to the Excel file
                wb.save(file_name)

                print("Historical data has been written to the sheet successfully.")
            else:
                print("No data found for the specified date range.")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to fetch data from the URL. Status Code: {response_session.status_code}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

# Read the date range from the Excel sheet
file_name = r"C:\Users\vhind\Desktop\a\Zerodha\Version_v0\Zerodha\NSE_data.xlsm"
wb = xw.Book(file_name)
sheet_name = "Main"
from_date = wb.sheets[sheet_name].range('C15').value
to_date = wb.sheets[sheet_name].range('C16').value

# Specify the index type for historical data (e.g., NIFTY 50)
index_type = "NIFTY%2050"

# Call the function to fetch and write the historical data
NseHistoricalData(index_type, from_date, to_date)
```

Comment: The status code 401 indicates that the request was not completed due to a lack of valid authentication credentials. Make sure you don't need some sort of api key to access this resource

Answer (score 1):

Try using an API Key when you make your request. You can create a free account from https://scrapeops.io/app/register/proxy

```
import urllib

def get_scrapeops_url(url):
    API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
    payload = {'api_key': API_KEY, 'url': url}
    proxy_url = 'https://proxy.scrapeops.io/v1/?' + urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
    return proxy_url

def NseHistoricalData(index_type, from_date, to_date):
    # url and headers
    session = requests.Session()
    response_session = requests.get(get_scrapeops_url(url), headers=headers)

    # rest of the code
```